# How to add a string with a literal backslash in mysql, using ruby/rails migrations?

Tags: mysql, rails-migrations

I'm trying to update a mariadb table column, to a string that contains a literal backslash.

I want the resulting string in the table to be

```
4.4 \(blah blah\)
```

I've tried

```
UPDATE table SET string = '4.4 \\(blah blah\\)' WHERE string = '4.4 (blah blah)';
```

This works when I run it in Sequel Pro, but when I run it as part of a ruby/rails migration, the result is that the column remains unchanged, ie. 4.4 (blah blah).

I've tried every combination of single quotes, double quotes, single backslash, double backslash. I also tried a triple backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) sql_mode.

> Enabling this mode disables the use of the backslash character () as
> an escape character within strings and identifiers. With this mode
> enabled, backslash becomes an ordinary character like any other, and
> the default escape sequence for LIKE expressions is changed so that no
> escape character is used.

```
mysql> create table my_table (
    -> string  varchar(255) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into my_table values
    -> ('4.4 (blah blah)');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (1.318 sec)

mysql> set session sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE my_table SET string = '4.4 \(blah blah\)' WHERE string = '4.4 (blah blah)';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from my_table;
+-------------------+
| string            |
+-------------------+
| 4.4 \(blah blah\) |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: In my migration I ended up with 
`def up
      execute <<-SQL
          set session sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
      SQL
      execute <<-SQL
        UPDATE my_table SET string = '4.4 \\(blah blah\\)' WHERE string = '4.4 (blah blah)';
      SQL
    end`
and that worked, thanks.